# DependencyProperty.Register textbox in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I am trying to get a textbox to display encrypted data and save any changes back to the document after encrypting it. This is what I have:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=UID, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="txtUID" Width="70"/>
```

Code behind:

```
public DependencyProperty UIDProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UID", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(""));
private string UID
{
    get { return Encryption.Decrypt((string)GetValue(UIDProperty)); }
    set { SetValue(UIDProperty, Encryption.Encrypt(value)); }
}
```

The problem is when the form loads and when I change the value nothing happens. The text box remains blank and the code never stops at the break points I set to catch the get and set of UID. What am I not doing right?

Comment: You can't do that.  What are you trying to defend against?

Comment: Try making it a public property and setting the trace=high.

Answer (score 1):

The "CLR-wrappers" for [dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) can only get called through code. The XAML parser is used the direct call of  the [DependencyObject.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.getvalue.aspx) and [DependencyObject.SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setvalue.aspx) methods.

To accomplish your task you can extend your binding with the [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

Comment: +1, WPF does not use CLR properties when reading and writing to a DependencyProperty. As for an IValueConverter, I'm not sold on the idea, but it is the best so far.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [debugging databindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx), if a binding is broken you should at least be able to retrieve the binding error.

There are various possible reasons, one of them being that the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) is not the control with the property. The fact that the breakpoint is not hit means nothing, that CLR property is just for your convenience (you should *not place any custom code* in it), if you do not use it in your code noone will, the binding system uses something like [`SetBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding.aspx).

Comment: No; the problem is that dependency properties don't use their accessors.

Comment: @SLaks: It's not, obviously the CLR-wrapper is not called by the binding system, but there would still be some encrypted data if the binding was not broken.

Answer (score 0):

the property string UDI is not being called because it is private.  For the XAML to have access you need to make it public.  And you need to set the datacontext to the code behind.

There may a problem with DependencyProperty but if the get and set are not called on UID then it is not getting that far.  First try without encyption to at least get binding debugged.

```
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=UID, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="txtUID" Width="70"/>
```

Code behind:

```
    public DependencyProperty UIDProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UID", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(""));
    string uid = string.empty;
    public string UID
    {
        get 
        { 
            //return Encryption.Decrypt((string)GetValue(UIDProperty));
            Debug.WriteLine("get called");
            return uid; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            // SetValue(UIDProperty, Encryption.Encrypt(value)); 
             Debug.WriteLine("set called");
             if(uid != value)
             {
                 uid = value;
                 NotifyPropertyChanged("UID");
             }
        }
    }
```

Notice UID is a public (not private property).

Comment: The CLR properties for a dependency property are not called by the binding system.

Comment: @sixlettervariables The problem statement includes "code never stops at the break points I set to catch the get and set of UID".   This is a simple test if the get and set are called.  I clearly state "There may a problem with DependencyProperty".   Even if there is a problem with the dependency property the debugger should be stopping at the line in the get and set.

Comment: No, it won't stop at the line with the get and set. The XAML binding system does not use the CLR properties for a `DependencyProperty`. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx): *"...the XAML processor that obtain property values from XAML processing also use GetValue rather than using the [CLR property] wrapper"*.

Comment: @sixlettervariables UID is a string .  Agree it may have a problem with the line "return Encryption.Decrypt((string)GetValue(UIDProperty))"  but if the binding to the string is working it should get to that line.

Comment: No, that is incorrect. I'll make my comment bold to help, **WPF does not use CLR properties when reading and writing to a DependencyProperty**.

Comment: @sixlettervariables You can bold, italicize and underline but I am but I am not incorrect.  The string property was not accessible by the XAML because is was private.  I reproduced the problem and remedy.  private = no call to set or get.  Public = successful calls to get and set.  The binding is to the TextBlock Text property.  If that line return Encryption.Decrypt((string)GetValue(UIDProperty)); throws an error then got to solve that problem but it cannot throw an error if it is not called.  If the string property is private it aint getting called by XAML binding.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Please review the .NET binding primer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx  "The target property must be a dependency property."  "Although not specified in the figure, it should be noted that the binding source object is not restricted to being a custom CLR object. WPF data binding supports data in the form of CLR objects and XML."   Target versus source can be tricky.  The UI element is the target.